# Maven 3.0.4 on Windows 7 with Java 1.7.0_11 was not able to connect to repositories

Tags: maven, windows-7, java-7

I have got the following error message on my java development project when I did

```
mvn clean install
```

Error was:

```
Error injecting: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon
```

and maven stopped to continue building. I have cleaned up the local maven repository, it did not help. I have downloaded Maven again, I did cleaning and I have restarted Windows as well. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around the net here as well and I found that java 7 could be responsible for this. I have tried with the suggested forcing IPv4 stack parameter as well

```
mvn -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true clean install
```

but it did not help me.

So I have changed the jdk version and I have selected java 1.6 update 39 first. I had success with it. Then I have download the newest jdk 1.7 update 13 and tried again. I did full local maven repository cleanup before (deleting the .m2 folder in my home directory).

With the newest java 7 update 13 the maven build was also successful again. So I have turned back to java7.